# How do I get YouTube's embed code validate against HTML5?

Tags: flash, html, youtube

My page validated error free against HTML5 until I added YouTube's embed code.

```
# Line 140, Column 132: Stray end tag param.

    …O30JM&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="tru

# Error Line 140, Column 183: Stray end tag param.

    …llowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="a

# Error Line 140, Column 238: Stray end tag param.

    …scriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/1rW

# Error Line 140, Column 430: Stray end tag embed.

    …ways" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Is there a way to get object, embed and param tags validate against HTML5 ?

Comment: Edited to render properly. Please use the code formatting facility

Comment: Short question aside: Why do you want to? HTML 5 is a *working draft* ... this isn't exactly ready for production use.

Comment: “HTML 5 is a working draft ... this isn't exactly ready for production use.” You might want to tell Google that then.

Comment: It might not be ready for production use, but it's much readier for production use than HTML4 or XHTML1.

Comment: Ironically youtubes html5 demo page http://www.youtube.com/html5 doesn't have a valid embed code either!

Answer (score 5):

Remove the end tags and replace them with self closing tags.

Eg.

```
<embed ...></embed>

<embed ... />
```

Comment: You could, but I find something nice about self closing tags :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Charlies answer, with some more detail:

Embed is a void element, i.e. it can have no content. Thus, it must not have closing tag, in the HTML serialization.

In the XHTML serialization it must be closed. XML parsers do not differentiate between self-closing tags and tags that are immediately (no white space) followed by a closing tag. But the latter is redundant and error prone, since white-space so easily slip in between the starting tag and the closing tag.

It may be written using the self-closing syntax, in the HTML serialization, which some authors, myself included, prefer as a style convention. It is ignored by the parsers, though.

Thus, the self closing syntax is always allowed on void elements, but sometimes redundant.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements